# Merging SAS datasets by different column names across several columns

Tags: merge, sas

I have 2 data sets that I want to merge by territory #...the first dataset has territory information including territory #, the second dataset has territory #'s but they are across 4 different columns titled drug_terr1, drug_terr2, drug_terr3, and drug_Terr4...I need to merge on all 4 columns because they each have different territory #'s and I want those numbers to be included in my merge with the dataset that has all the territory information...I tried a rename but that didn't work because it only changed the first column...is there a way to combine all this data, and rename it by territory # so I can do the merge?

ultimately would like it to look like this, but need to get the 4 columns from 'terrfile' to become 1 column called territory_nbr so I can merge.

```
 %let output = E:\Horizon\Adhoc\AH\;
%let terrs =\\uslsasas1\E$\Horizon\IMS Processing\Weekly Data\20161230\Demo\;
libname terrs "&terrs.";
%let curr_process_wk = '12-30-2016';
%let curr_quarter =_q1;
**0 Grab pskw;
data pskw_data;
set PSKW.PSKWMaster ;
where week in ('12-16-2016','12-23-2016','12-30-2016','01-06-2017') and CopayType ="FBD" and FNRX=1 and pme_id in (46,42,55,38) and product in ('DUEXIS','VIMOVO','PENNSAID')
and
(COBPrimaryRejectCode1 in ('75','76') or COBPrimaryRejectCode2 in ('75', '76') or COBPrimaryRejectCode3  in  ('75' , '76'));
run;
proc sort data=pskw_data;
by imsid;
run;

** 01 Grab tbl HCP;
proc sort data=ims.tblhcp (where = (week = &curr_process_wk.) keep = week imsid first_name last_name address1 address2 city state zip spec)
          out = IMS_demo (drop = week);
      by IMSID;
run;

** 02 Grab tbl terrs_by_imsid;
data terrfile;
set terrs.wd2_terrs_by_imsid&curr_quarter.;
run;

proc sort data = terrfile;
by imsid;
run;
** 03 Grab tbl roster;
data roster (keep = territorycode repname territoryname teamname);
set ims.tblRoster;
   repname = trim(left(FirstName))||" "||trim(left(LastName));
run;
**04 link ;
data combine_dbs;
merge pskw_data (in=in1)
ims.tblhcp (in=in2);
by imsid;
if in1;
run;
data territories;  ***can't merge because territory code is not in terrfile, just 4 columns as I mentioned above***;
merge terrfile (in=in1)
roster (in=in2);
by territorycode;
if in2;
run;
```

Comment: Can you show what your data looks like atm?

Comment: What fields do you want from territory master file (the one that has one record per territory)?  Since you want to combine it four times with your fact table (the one with up to four territory codes) you will need to make four names for each field to store up to four different values.

Comment: I want something called IMS_ID from terrfiles so that I can add that into my roster dataset ultimately.

Comment: "need to get the 4 columns from 'terrfile' to become 1 column called territory_nbr so I can merge." This is your question. Post what you have, what you want and we can help you create the new variable. In this case your code isn't helpful, examples of data is better.

Comment: Or SQL can join on a field that has a calculation, so you could do something like a.terr = catt(var1, var2, var3, var4) in your join.

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge the fact table with the lookup table four times. Let's say your territory identifier is called `ID` in your lookup table you want to take the field `IMS_ID` from it.  Let's also assume your four fields in your fact table are named `ID1-ID4`.

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as 
     select a.*
          , b.ims_id as ims_id1
          , c.ims_id as ims_id2
          , d.ims_id as ims_id3
          , e.ims_id as ims_id4
     from FACT a
     left join LU b on a.id1=b.id
     left join LU c on a.id2=c.id
     left join LU d on a.id3=d.id
     left join LU e on a.id4=e.id
   ;
quit;
```

In your example it looks `ROSTER` is your `FACT` table and `TERRFILES` is your `LU` table.  Your `ID` variable looks like it is name `TERRITORYCODE`, at least in your lookup file.  Hard to tell what the four variables in `ROSTER` are named.